# How do we get a specific answer in case of limits when we get 0/0 form?

Tags: limits, functions

Lets consider a function, $$f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$$
We know that if we plot this graph we get  a straight line throughout on $y=1$.

We see that when we insert value of $x=0$ in this function, here $\frac{0}{0}$ seems to be equal to $1$. Here I suppose that we can write $\frac{x}{x}=1$ for all real numbers except for $0$ because every real number divided by itself gives answer as $1$. But this fact don't hold good in case of $0$.

Another way is that we approach $x=0$ in this function $f(x)$ from left hand side and right hand side. But in this case also we can get answer for points extremely right and left to our input i.e $x=0$ but we can't get answer for value of $x$ at exactly $0$ as we can approach infinitely close to $0$ from left hand side and right hand side but can't reach at point exactly $0$.

Similarly consider another function, $$g(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$$ Here if we insert value of $x=2$ we get $\frac{0}{0}$ form. But on simplifying this function we get $g(x)=x+2$ and for $x=2$ we get answer as $4$. Here also we can simplify this function for all real numbers except $2$. For more clarification let us put value of $x=2$ in this function $g(x)$.
$g(2)=\frac{2^2-4}{2-2}$. Its simplifies to yield $g(2)=\frac{(2+2)(2-2)}{2-2}$. Here we can't divide $(2-2)$ in numerator with $(2-2)$ in denominator and write it as $1$. So we can only get answer for $g(x)$ at $x=2$ i.e $g(2)=4$, when we assume $\frac{2-2}{2-2}$ i.e $\frac{0}{0}=1$.

So it seems like we can only get exact answer in case of limits in form of $\frac{0}{0}$, when we assume $\frac{0}{0}=1$.

Comment: Limits are not direct substitutions!

Comment: You should not think of $0/0$ as $1$. What about $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}x$?

Comment: Pictures are not a proof although they usually give us an idea what is going on. But in the case $\frac{x}{x}$ , this is not needed anyway since this expression is obviously always $1$ , unless $x=0$ in which case it is not defined. Therefore , the limit is obvious here.

Comment: If we do not know anything about the concrete functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ besides that they tend to $0$ for $x\rightarrow 0$ , the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for $x\rightarrow 0$ can be any real number (just consider $\frac{rx}{x}$) or might not even exist. Conisder for example , $\frac{x}{x^2}$

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined because it can be every real number $r$ , since $0\cdot r=0$ holds for every real $r$. So, we are forced to consider this expression as undefined.

Comment: @Peter. Use L'Hospital rule !!

Comment: In some sense you're correct that in that if you consider $\lim_{x \to a}$, when $x$ is "really close" to $a$ say $x = a \pm \delta$ for some small $\delta > 0$, then you're dividing non-zero numbers:
$$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{(x - a) f(x)}{x - a} \approx \frac{\delta f(a \pm \delta)}{\delta} = f(a \pm \delta)$$
(i.e., $\frac{\delta}{\delta} = 1$ as usual for numbers that are non-zero). To make the above an equal sign, you actually need $\lim_{\delta \to 0} f(a + \delta)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are various indeterminate forms and one of which is $0/0$. But first recall the quotient rule $$\lim_{x \to a}\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]=\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)}.$$

This holds only if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x) \neq 0$. But this does not mean that if its zero, the limit cannot be obtained. The [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) states that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $$\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)} = \frac{\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to a} g'(x)}.$$

---

From your example, it really seems that $f(0)$ should be 1 as $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ which is equal to one for all $x$ not equal to zero in the domain. However, $x = 0$ is not in the domain which means that $f(0)$ is undefined.

You introduced the notion of approaching from the left-hand side and the right-hand side. This is the [one-sided limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit). You are right that the one-sided limits are both equal to one which means that the limit is one. For a moment, let's say that $0/0 = 1$ to fix the issue in this function.

But then, consider the function $$g(x) = \frac{\cos x}{\pi - 2x}.$$ As $x$ approaches $\frac{1}{2}\pi$, $\cos x$ approaches 0. The expression $\pi - 2x$ also approaches zero. Since both are differentiable, you can use the LHR to solve for the limit as follows: $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{\pi - 2x} = \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-\sin x}{-2} \\ = \frac{-1}{-2} \\ =\frac{1}{2}.$$ If we try to make $g$ continuous at $x = \frac{1}{2}\pi$, we should set $0/0 = 1/2$.

We declared earlier that $0/0 = 1$. Now, $0/0 = 1/2$. Which is it?

From @Peter's comment, $0/0$ is undefined as $0 \cdot r = 0$ for all real $r$. This implies that if somehow, $0/0$ is defined, it needs to be equal to all real numbers which cannot be true. Therefore, you should not think that $0/0$ is $1$.